# Не работает плагин telescope для neovim

Tags: vim

Всем привет. Решила с недавних пор перейти на neovim (много о нем наслышана и захотелось попробовать). Установила себе AstroNvim, прочитала, что это один из самых популярных конфигов, посмотрела много видосов, решила начать с него. Но все время вылезает проблема с плагином telescope, много чего перечитала, ничего полезного не нашла...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю что плагину для работу нужна (доступная в `PATH`?) одна из утилит поиска текста в файлах: `find`, `fd` или `rg`.

Comment: Установила через pip библиотеку either - стало открываться окно поиск, но сам по себе поиск не работает, не идентифицирует файлы по названию...

Comment: `find`, `fd`, `rg` это всё консольные приложения, не совсем понятно причём тут `either`.. Запустите консоль и проверьте доступна ли там любая из этих трех команд. Есть правда нюанс что в Windows есть своя `find` и скорее всего нужна не она. Впрочем всё выше это мои предположения, т.к. с neovim не работал, просто руководствуюсь логикой..

Comment: Библиотеку ```either``` ставить не надо. Это просто слово "любой". Вас просят установить любое из приложений find, fd, rg